# Why can't I set <Home> or t_kh in my vimrc file?

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings, terminal

I'm having some problems remapping my home key; it works when I run Vim from tmux but not when I run it from a regular xterm without tmux. It looks like they're sending different escape codes and Vim only picks up on tmux's one for some reason.

I tried mucking about with a lot of `TERM` values, to no avail. So I figured I'd just hard-code this escape code in my vimrc and move on:

```
set nocompatible

" `^[` is the escape character.
set <Home>=^[OH
set t_kh=^[OH

echo &t_kh

noremap <Home> :echoerr "home!"<CR>
```

Starting with `$ vim -u vimrc` Vim outputs `^[OH`, which is expected. But after I've started Vim the setting seems to be not set:

```
:set t_kh?
E846: Key code not set: t_kh?
:verbose set t_kh?
E846: Key code not set: t_kh?
```

And the remapped home key doesn't work. Manually running `:set <Home>` or `:set t_kh` fixes the problem; I can now use my custom `<Home>` mapping.

Why aren't these options taking effect? How can I make them take effect?

I have no plugins and am using Vim 8.0.586 on Arch Linux.

Comment: Is something setting `'term'` after your vimrc is loaded?

Comment: Don't think so @jamessan, `:verbose set term?` just gives `term=xterm-256color` without extra information. Also tried without plugins/vimrc, and I get exactly the same results.

Comment: You say you have no plugins but do you have anything else? See `:scriptnames`

Comment: It loads the default plugins from ` /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/` @laktak, but other than that nothing.

Comment: I guess I'm out of ideas - I have the same version on arch but can't replicate your issue. Try a different terminal? I'm using urxvt.

Comment: Vim starts termcap after reading the vimrc but before running the `VimEnter` autocommands, so have you tried defining the keys there? Bit of a long shot, but maybe there's something interfering there.

Comment: Using the `VimEnter` autocommand doesn't help @Antony

Comment: Yeah, I could switch to urxvt I suppose @laktak ... But I've been using xterm for 15 years; I'd rather not switch... But it's starting to look like that'll be easier than fixing this :-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this in [`:help xterm-function-keys`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/term.txt.html#xterm-function-keys):

```
An xterm can send function keys F1 to F4 in two modes: vt100 compatible or
not.  Because Vim may not know what the xterm is sending, both types of keys
are recognized.  The same happens for the <Home> and <End> keys.
                        normal                  vt100
        <F1>    t_k1    <Esc>[11~       <xF1>   <Esc>OP     <xF1>-xterm
        <F2>    t_k2    <Esc>[12~       <xF2>   <Esc>OQ     <xF2>-xterm
        <F3>    t_k3    <Esc>[13~       <xF3>   <Esc>OR     <xF3>-xterm
        <F4>    t_k4    <Esc>[14~       <xF4>   <Esc>OS     <xF4>-xterm
        <Home>  t_kh    <Esc>[7~        <xHome> <Esc>OH     <xHome>-xterm
        <End>   t_@7    <Esc>[4~        <xEnd>  <Esc>OF     <xEnd>-xterm

When Vim starts, <xF1> is mapped to <F1>, <xF2> to <F2> etc.  This means that
by default both codes do the same thing.  If you make a mapping for <xF2>,
because your terminal does have two keys, the default mapping is overwritten,
thus you can use the <F2> and <xF2> keys for something different.
```

Setting *both* `<Home>` and `<xHome>` seems to work well! Because we *only* want this to take effect inside xterm I added a `&term` check (tmux is `screen-256color`):

```
set nocompatible

if &term == "xterm-256color"
    " `^[` is the escape character.
    set <Home>=^[OH
    set <xHome>=^[OH
endif

noremap <Home> :echoerr "home!"<CR>
```

I'd be lying if I'd say that I fully comprehend all of the above, but it seems to work well without ill effects in my testing.